du command fails with error "invalid max-depth of 1"
A weird situation. I have been using this command below successfully on Ubuntu 20 and earlier to get a list of all directories with highest disk usage sorted descending:
sudo du -ah --max-depth=1  / | sort -hr
However, when I run this on a latest Ubuntu 22 server, it fails with the following error message:
du: invalid maximum depth ‘1‘
Try 'du --help' for more information.

The OS details are:
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

What could be the issue ? It seems like it just doesn't like that parameter of --max-depth even though it should exist and work.

Are you sure there's no invisible character around 1?

@choroba you are right. Dang it. Probably some copy paste issues. I pasted in plain text first and then in terminal and it worked.. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Can you also share how your problemis related to programming? If du throws an error, this might be better suited at superuser.com or askubuntu.com

Are you sure there's no invisible character around 1? I'm getting the error when I add a WORD JOINER after the number:
$ du -ah --max-depth=1$'\xe2\x81\xa0'⁠⁠ / | sort -hr
du: invalid maximum depth ‘1⁠’
Try 'du --help' for more information.

